# What aircraft did this canopy come from?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

This canopy was found near [Wetumka, Oklahoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetumka,_Oklahoma) in a small creek running through my best friend's property. The canopy is about 12 feet long. Can anyone tell me what aircraft it came from, or who I could contact to ask?

A [loving cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loving_cup) from 1906 dedicated to a Miss Grace Walling Spore from the USS Alliance Navy Ship was also found in same creek recently. I contacted the family myself and they knew nothing about the loving cup or any crashed plane that may have been carrying it.

[image: Photo of canopy #2]
[image: Photo of canopy #3]

Here is another picture... I do not know if was in a crash.

[image: Photo of canopy #4]

It could have washed down creek I suppose, but why would a jet canopy have been in a creek? I am searching for what kind of craft it belongs to.

- Location: A creek in Wetumka, Oklahoma
- Rumored date/pilot: 1944 / Loyde Christian
- Object length: ~12 ft

[image: Serial number on a bracket]

Comment: @BrendaSeitz It is quite difficult to make out anything from this image alone. Do you have any other photos from another angle perhaps?

Comment: Tentatively I'd suggest a B47 - although there's nothing near you on this database of crashes http://okwreckchasing.org/database.htm

Comment: Why is everyone assuming a crash? Couldn't it have just been moved there?

Comment: All -- This is not a discussion forum.  Please move all of this to chat if you could: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar

Comment: Is it possible to get a closer look at the canopy without disturbing it? There may be part numbers on the metal frame (inside or outside) that could be clues as to what type of aircraft it is.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts. If you really want to delete it, either hit the delete button, or flag it and ask a moderator to delete it for you.

Comment: if your rumoured date is correct, it won't be a jet. If your rumoured name is correct, a FOIA request to the USAF might yield information.

Comment: Can you provide any more details about what the link is between the rumored date/pilot and the object?  Also, what is the metallic plate that you are holding, and was it attached to the object? I agree with @PartyArk, it bears a striking resemblance to the canopy from a B-47.  Finally, the canopy frame should be a serialized part.  IF you can find an S/N that would go a long way.

Comment: @tiimas,  the plate is off the canopy,  and the only thing with numbers on it, also found another piece of the plane...I can't find any info  on a crash, but other things like silverware from the uss Alliance has been found along with the loving cup.  I assume that stainless steel plate is the serial number.? any help would be helpful. thank you

Comment: You've mentioned that the canopy is about 12' long. Can you get an approximate measurement of the width, as well? It looks like one half is pretty well buried (I'd suggest leaving it that way until you know what you've got your hands on) so maybe see if you can get a measurement from edge to center then double it. A height measurement may help, as well.

Comment: Sending your pictures and those dimensions to the [Public Affairs Officer at Tinker AFB](http://www.tinker.af.mil/ContactUs.aspx) in Oklahoma City might get you some help, as well. It may not be an Air Force jet, but I'd imagine there are some plane geeks on the base who may be able to identify what we haven't been able to.

Answer (score 1):

This canopy probably came off a Boeing B-47.

[image]

I do know of at least two mishaps involving B-47s in Oklahoma but both occurred in places other than Wetumka.  I'll do a little more investigating on this.

Another possibility is that the previous landowners acquired this part as scrap at some point and left it there on their property for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you so much, some Sterling silver from 1906 was also found, near this canopy

Comment: I don't know if the two are related.

Comment: We read somewhere a plane carrying a silver set...tiffany loving cup from 1906  was on plane from new York going to okc. Google info on  john walling spore and Grace walling spore. This cup we found was dedicated to her. It's like the plane was carrying artifacts to a museum,  we also found a rock carving ....old,   by canopy.  Not in wetumka, more like henryetta ok is where it was found.  Any help you can give is helpful....

Comment: And the plane was flying this stuff in 1944 I think

Comment: Well if it's a B47 which this canopy came off of, it wasn't flying in 1944.

Comment: Hmmm. Thank you, any help is appreciated,  I never knew for sure it was 1944....

Comment: A B-47's canopy has glass for all three segments. The one in this question looks like it has metal for one of the end segments (presumably the back).

Comment: Those photos don't look like metal; it's just discolored plexiglass

Comment: A B-47 from Witchita KS broke apart over Tulsa OK March 13 1958.  Its canopy would have to have been transported after the crash to get to Henryetta OK.  ... but there isn't enough data to say that this a B-47 canopy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the F series. The oldest aircraft I can find with a canopy like this is the F9 Cougar, though other aircraft in the series also use this kind of canopy.

Comment: thank you....do u know of one crashing going from new York to okc oklahoma?  with sterling silver from the uss alliance  dated 1906.  the plane parts are around henryetta oklahoma in a creek bed....the tiffany loving cup dedicated to grace Wallace  and some sterling silverware has also been found..just trying to gather any info on pilot. or crash...if you can help me...all I have is phone Internet.

Comment: It would help to post a picture of the F9 to compare with the pictures in the question and point out the similarities.

Comment: This is a pic of one, best shot I could find of the canopy, looks like it is sectioned the same way as the one you found, but the canopy varied over the different sub-models of the F9, so may be a bit different [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/F9F_Cougars_of_VA-192_and_VFP-61_over_Formosa_1957.jpg)

Comment: @jakefaulkner thank you, I agree that's the aircraft...found another piece of it with the grey star